# What could be the reason my old main SSD is not visible in device manager/partition software

Tags: usb, partitioning, ssd

I recently swapped a 1 TB SSD for 2 TB as my main drive running Windows. Now I was to use it as a secondary drive for other software and media (pictures, videos, documents).

I open the same partition manager (EaseUS Partition Master Free Edition), I cannot view it. But I can view another hard drive connected to the same USB port (I have an external SATA to USB device). Same thing happens on different USB.

Before cloning the old SSD to the 2TB SSD, I did not think to change the drive letter or modify the old SSD in any way. I figured first I would clone and swap, then I would make my modifications afterwards.

I also attempted to use a different computer running Ubuntu to view the disk using GParted without any luck.

Could there be a reason I do not see my old SSD?

Comment: Does the new SSD show up in: 1) Device Manager (devmgmt.msc – easy to find in "View by connection"), 2) Disk Management (diskmgmt.msc)? I would almost bet you'll find it in diskmgmt marked "offline due to duplicate ID".

Answer (score 0):

grawity, I ended up swapped the old SSD back it its original SATA connection. I booted the system and used the partitioning tool to delete all partitions (requiring reboot). Then I swapped the new SSD back in.

I should have verified it with the dvmgmt.msc utility. But forcing it work as before did it for this case. I'll use the software tools in the future.

Comment: @bertieb I did not find the answer that solved it, so I added my own answer. There were no answers added.

Comment: My mistake, apologies. Thank you for closing the loop. It is your answer and your call but I'd take out the bit directed at a specific user :)